# How to use Details band to display multiple data sets

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a *JasperReports*'s report with 10 rows fetched from the main query..

When i run the report it will show 10 rows without a problem.

**Now when i add another band with fields of a data set in a list item. It is repeated for every record in the main report!.** :(

How can i avoid this situation and change the second details band to print when the main report data has finished printing on the first band?

I would want to achieve this without going for sub-reports as it's difficult to maintain many files for a single report.

Comment: Can you put the list component in the summary band, would it work there?

Comment: No, stretchy components will not be allowed in other bands as far as i know.

Answer (score 1):

I have learned a lot on jasper reports over time and I'm posting the answer for my very own question to help someone in future.

What you need to do is for complex, Multi-query reports you create the main report with a simple query like this.

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL
```

What this means is that when it's run main report details band will have a **single iteration**. That means if we have used the **SYSDATE** field in the details band it will **print once**.

OK, now if you follow the following steps you should be able to achieve the above task successfully.

> 1. Add two details band to the report (you must be having one details band by default, to add another right click --> add another detail band)

---

> 2. Add two data-sets to the main report (right click on the report and select Add Dataset)

---

> 3. Now all you need to do is use those two data sets in the previously created details bands by using either a **list** item or **table** item (personally I would recommend table as you can do lot of advanced stuff in that)

---

```
Hope this will help someone in the future. let me know if you need more help!. Cheers!!
```